# New Behringer C-2 microphone malfunctioning

Tags: microphone, noise, stereo, behringer

So, I recently bought this stereo pair, small diaphragm condensers.

One of them works fine

Another doesn't work and generates lots of noise while it is set to unchanged sound picking mode (those mics can be set to "-10 dB", "low cut" or "unchanged" sound picking modes). I works fine when on low cut or on -10 dB, however.

Tried changing cables, ports in my audio interface - nothing

Have I already damaged it?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a manufacturing defect in the signal chain (possibly an electrical short); I would suggest seeking a replacement.

Answer (score 1):

these are interchangeable capsules. Try switching the capsules around and attempt to further isolate the fault to the body or the capsule. This will also be a chance to give the capsules connection plates a bit of a clean and see if that helps. Otherwise, if you can identify the fault, get it repaired under warranty.